# Visual regression test - Extract elements of GUI-Screenshot - MSER OpenCV

Tags: image-processing, opencv, image-segmentation, edge-detection, local-features

For a visual regression test I need to compare screenshots of webpages (different release-versions). I started with pixel by pixel compare. Actually I split the screenshot in different parts (maybe 10x10 rectangles) and compare the histograms of correspondending parts.

Now I try to find an approach to find regions of interest (with coordinates and/or bounding box) automatically (tried edge detection and so on) like this:

[image]

[Example of image segmentation](http://browserbite.com/cross-browser-testing-using-machine-learning/)

I found different articles on the web dealing with blob-detection. One method for that is Maximally stable extremal regions (MSER) which is provided in OpenCV.

[Feature Detection and Description](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/features2d/doc/feature_detection_and_description.html)

Now my questions:

1. Is MSER applicable for the given problem
2. Are there simpler approaches then MSER
3. Can someone give me some introductions to use MSER from OpenCV in Java (unfortunately I haven´t experience with OpenCV or JavaCV. Anyway I installed it on my machine.)